# What's a simple way in Google Chrome to insert Javascript into sites?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I would like to be able to add custom snippets of javascript to any site that matches a regex. This is mostly because of sites that I use daily because of specialized content, but which have a poor design. I want to be able to do something like:

- Visit site See that sidebar overwrites content
- Whip out developer tools, find div id for sidebar
- Edit a snippet of javascript which is executed on document.ready for this domain:

  ```
  $('#sidebar-right').remove();
  ```

A bit of searching for user scripts tells me that I need to be writing a Chrome extension, which seems unfortunate and overkill. Is there not an easier way, or an extension which is nothing but a javascript editor that assigns snippets to domains? I'd really like to be able to edit in Chrome itself, or at least have a file that I can just leave open in MacVim all the time. An extension requires unloading/installing to update as far as I can tell.

If I just had one big javascript file, that would be fine. I'd just wrap my customizations in domain checks.

Bonus love if I can write in CoffeeScript.

Comment: I wonder... would this be possible to do without an extension?

Comment: @bhuga, can you change the accepted answer please? dotjs is no longer maintained, and your answer about tampermonkey should be the accepted one

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Is this possible to do without an extension? as extensions has rights to read all data and websites we visit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is to use the Tampermonkey chrome extension.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo

Answer (score 13):

Why not dotjs http://defunkt.io/dotjs/ ? It's local, you can version it with git, you can easily take it to another computer...

Comment: Sadly this is only OSX though.

Comment: Sadly this extension is no longer maintained.

Comment: Dotjs now mentions [Witchcraft](https://github.com/luciopaiva/witchcraft) as its successor.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative that neatly solves the problem is [Custom JavaScript for websites](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en). You just need to install the extension, which takes around 2 seconds, and then you can immediately start typing your custom JavaScript for the specified website.

[image: Custom JavaScript for websites example]

The extension automatically recognizes the current website, so all you need to do is write your code and click on `Save`. You can also easily import `jQuery` or your external scripts for convenience.

Comment: curious what's the advantage of this vs tampermonkey.

Answer (score 4):

[Custom JavaScript for Websites 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/ddbjnfjiigjmcpcpkmhogomapikjbjdk) is an alternative to Custom JavaScript for Websites, with some bug fixes and sync scripts across devices feature.

Answer (score 4):

[Witchcraft](https://github.com/luciopaiva/witchcraft) is another Google Chrome extension for loading custom Javascript and CSS, and it is supposedly for more avanced users. The older [dotjs](https://github.com/luciopaiva/witchcraft) project repository lists Witchcraft as its successor.

[image: Witchcraft toolbar menu]

Answer (score 3):

Snippets are available directly in Chrome Devtools

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is Greasemonkey. But wait, Greasemonkey is for Firefox only, right? Turns out, [you can install Greasemonkey user-scripts as native Chrome add-ons](http://mashable.com/2010/02/01/google-chrome-greasemonkey-2/). Just go to [userscripts.org](http://www.userscripts.org/) and hit the Install button on one of them, and Chrome will automatically convert it into a native add-on. Then, write your own and install it using Chrome.

Note: This only works in Chrome 4.0.

Comment: Firefox is great for having Greasemonkey, but it's so cool that Chrome supports those user-scripts natively. Much easier to manage them as add-ons than in a separate Greasemonkey interface.

Comment: This isn't quite what I want, unfortunately. There's no easy way to edit those in a hurry, or create a new one from scratch. I'm not really interested in community user scripts--this is about personal customization.

Comment: You can make them really quickly (see [this one](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/12897)), and make a simple HTML file that hosts them, and open them locally. What's so hard about it?

Answer (score 0):

In 2024: **[Violentonkey](https://github.com/violentmonkey/violentmonkey)** is open source alternative to the now-proprietary **Tampermonkey**